Pitclipse and java module
I use Pitclipse for a while on java <9 projects.
But when I use Pitclipse on java 9+ module-based project it fails:

"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.slf4j not found, required by my_module"

PitTest works well on this project using maven plugin.
module my_module {
    requires org.slf4j;
}

I'm using latest Pitclipse release v2.2.1.v20230330-0839.
Thanks

Please provide a minimal reproducible example. No issues with FindException has been reported to Pitclipse so far. Does your problem persist after you have deleted the launch configuration and tried again?
